# Enable file upload when check box is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've check box which I want that if show=true (show = Boolean type) enable the file upload so by default the check box is not checked and the file upload is disable,how can I do that?
I try with the following code which is not working well, when you click the enable/disable not working .

```
$(function () {
    $("#show").change(function () {
       $("#fileUpload").toggle(this.checked).prop("disabled", false);
    });
});
$("#fileUpload").toggle(this.checked).prop("disabled", true);




<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.show, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.show)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.show)
    </div>
</div>


    <div class="form-group">

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="file" id="fileUpload"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use just hide the fileupload until the checkbox has been ticked?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#uploads').hide();
    $('#enable_uploads').change(function(){
        $('#uploads').toggle()
    });
});
```

like this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E3PHP/